# How to add carousel-indicators using custom post types and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to dynamically add carousel-indicators to my slider that I created using Custom Post Type and Wordpress.

I have a custom post type called room.
This is what I have done so far but its not working:

```
<?php if( have_rows('room') ): $i = 0; ?>
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php while ( have_rows('room') ): the_row(); ?>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php if($i == 0) echo 'active'; ?>"></li>
                    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>  
                  </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

```
 <?php
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'room',);
                    $slider_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<!--
                    <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

-->
                    <?php if(have_posts() ) : while( $slider_query->have_posts() ) : $slider_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li data-target="#jumboCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $slider_query->current_post; ?>" <?php if( $slider_query->current_post == 0) : ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>></li>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                </ol>
```